# Does opaleye support upsert / INSERT ON CONFLICT?

Tags: haskell, opaleye

I'm trying to create a query like:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, level)
VALUES (1, 0)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET level = users.level + 1;
```

However I can't see how to do this with opaleye? Is this not supported?

Strangely we have [`Insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-0.6.7004.2/docs/Opaleye-Manipulation.html#t:Insert) defined with a field of [`iOnConflict :: Maybe OnConflict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-0.6.7004.2/docs/Opaleye-Manipulation.html#t:OnConflict). However `OnConflict` is defined as: `data OnConflict = DoNothing` so it just looks like a placeholder for now?

Following through the issue listed on github, I see it leads to this eventual PR: https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/pull/385/files but I can't really make sense of it? I'm not sure if it's implementing just the placeholder, or it actually implements the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you will generally get a quicker, and probably better, response to these kinds of questions if you 
[file a new issue on the Opaleye repo](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/issues/new).

Opaleye currently only supports `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.  I'm happy to look into supporting more functionality though.  Please chime in with a new issue or on [a relevant existing one](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/issues/215).